# Does Java JDK 6 allow non-generic legacy code?

Tags: java, generics

Does java JDK 6 support old non-generic collections or will it break existing code at run time?

If it does support it do you have to enable it?

So for example:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(5);

Alpha a = new Alpha();
a.insert(list);

for (Integer integer : list) {
  System.out.println(integer);
}
```

Non-Generic (legacy code):

```
public class Alpha {
  public void insert(List list) { 
    list.add(new String("50"));
  }
}
```

This compiles fine but breaks at runtime. I thought it would run fine and the compiler would just warn you.

Comment: The compiler won't warn you if you don't use generics. Period.

Comment: So Java 6 is not compatible with legacy code?

Comment: I didn't said that. Java 6 is definitely compatible with legacy code. It only won't warn when using incorrect raw types during compiletime. You would have exactly the same problem in older Java versions when you don't use generics.

Comment: Even though java is compatible with legacy code, in your example it simply breaks because it tries to convert the element in the list, which is a string, to an Integer (which causes a ClassCastException). This would work: for (Object o: list){System.out.println(o);}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generics sort-of only exist at compile-time. (Not quite; there's still metadata all over the place, but the object types themselves aren't affected, and in particular the array backing an `ArrayList` will still be an `Object[]`. That's very important here.) You can *always* use a generic type as if it's a non-generic type - the compiler will warn you, but the class itself can't stop you from doing it.

Your code breaks because you're implicitly casting each element of the array to Integer here:

```
for (Integer integer : list) {
    System.out.println(integer);
}
```

How would you *expect* that to be handled at execution-time? To be clear, the compiled code is roughly equivalent to:

```
for (Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    Integer integer = (Integer) list.next();
    System.out.println(integer);
}
```

Imagine you're in a world without generics, and think what that would do if you'd got a `String` in the list (as indeed you have, thanks to `Alpha`). The exact same thing (a `ClassCastException`) will occur *with* generics.

Comment: Yup, i got it, nice explanation. I went to joel spolsky talk in london about Stackoverflow you was mentioned as a great contributor to the community by him now i know why. :)

Comment: @nakul: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. I suspect you'd be best off asking a new question to be honest.

Comment: sure, I will.But i will wait for your reply

Answer (score 2):

The compiler will warn you about this.

Run javac with the -Xlint option for full details.

> warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type java.util.List 
>   list.add(new String("50"));

If you want to use an untyped (raw type) list then just create one using similar legacy code:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
```

but your code will still fail at runtime when you cast the String you added to the List to an Integer.

Comment: Yup i got it, i did not know about -Xlint, thanks for mentioning it.